# how to invoke a method with form start-up?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

my question is very simple... i created a Method but i don't really know how to invoke it once with ChildForm opening, here is the method code:

```
private void ShowMainPanel(Panel MainPanel)
    {
        if (panelEssentialRules.Visible == false)
            EssentialRulesFormTrans.ShowSync(panelEssentialRules);
    }
```

here is what i tried to do... i tried to put the method within the

```
public FORMNAME()
{

}
```

as showing below

```
    public partial class EssentialRulesForm : Form
{
    public EssentialRulesForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        hideMainPanel();
        ShowMainPanel(panelEssentialRules); //The invoked methoed

    }
```

with this... when i try to open the child form, the components dosn't load and it only shows me a white screen(form)
can you help me guys to somehow invoke my private method once with childForm openinig. Thank you!

Comment: Use `Form.Load` event handler. Do not add custom code to the Form constructor.

Comment: What exactly is `EssentialRulesFormTrans.ShowSync`? Sounds like it is causing the application to lock up.

Comment: @JohnWu it's how i show the event of BunifuTransition applied to a panel (in my case)

Comment: @aepot yeah that worked good. thank you